# Still able to access a struct that has been freed

Tags: c, struct, free, c99

So, I have a struct:

```
tyepdef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    double value;
} NodeT, *NodeTP;
```

and I have three functions:

```
int deleteNode(NodeTP p)
{
    free(p);
    p = NULL;

    return 1;
}

int deleteOne(NodeTP list)
{
    if (list->next != NULL)
        deleteOne(list->next);
    else 
        deleteNode(list);

    return 1;
}

int print(NodeT list)                                                           
{                                                                               
    printf("%lf\n", list.value);                                                

    if (list.next != NULL)                                                      
        print(*list.next);                                                      

    return 1;                                                                   
}
```

deleteOne will hand the final node in the list to deleteNode so that the memory can be freed. When a node is initialized, no memory is allocated for next, until it is needed. instead, it is initially set to be NULL. This is why I don't free(p->next).

So, if I have a list of nodes (let's say their values are 3.5, 2.5, 1.2, 3.6)
the print function will print the following:

```
3.5
2.5
1.2
3.6
```

Then, if the final node is deleted, and I print again, the following is printed:

```
3.5
2.5
1.2
3.6
```

If I delete another node, I get an error because I'm trying to free memory that has already been freed.

It seems as though print is accessing a memory location still, that has already been freed. However, it seems like it shouldn't be trying to read this if the 'next' node is equal to NULL. 
I realize this is undefined behaviour, but how can I fix this?

Comment: I cant see your calling code, but should deleteNode() be accepting a pointer to p?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. It's not a "guaranteed crash" or "guaranteed garbage values". The solution: if you need to access some memory, then don't free it.

Comment: The `p = NULL;` inside your `deleteNode` function has no effect. All you're doing is modifying a *local* copy of the pointer. So when you call `deleteNode(list);` (adding the missing semicolon here), you're not actually changing the value of `list`. The call to `deleteNode` will `free` what is *pointed to* by `list`, but `list` is passed by value to `deleteNode` and therefore remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

When the `tail node` of a linked list is deleted, it is the programmer's responsibility to set the previous' node's `next` element to NULL.

When the `tail node` is `free()`ed, the memory that the node occupied will continue to hold the values it was assigned (when it was a node) until that memory is used for another purpose.  Hence, it is not a good idea to continue to reference that memory after freeing it.

Sometimes, I write my own `free()` function to ensure that the pointer passed to free is no longer capable of accessing the memory.  Something like this:

```
void myFree(void **ptr)
   {
   free(*ptr);
   *ptr=NULL;
   }
```

Then, when the tail node is freed, the parent node's next pointer is automatically set to NULL:

```
void myFreeTailNode(NodeT **head)
   {
   NodeT *parentNode   = NULL;

   if(NULL == head)
      return;

   if(NULL == *head)
      return;

   if(NULL == (*head)->next)
      myFree((void **)head);
   else
      {
      for(parentNode = *head; parentNode->next->next; parentNode=parentNode->next)
          /*Do Nothing */ ;

      MyFree((void **)&parentNode->next);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this if you want NULL assigned outside the function:

```
int deleteNode(NodeTP * p)
{
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;

    return 1;
}
```

And change your calls to deleteNode.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to affect how the code performs at all

Comment: You need to apply the same change to deleteOne if you want list to be modified outside that function.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but... NodeTP is the same as NodeT *, so shouldn't this change make no difference?

Also, if I make this change to deleteOne, won't this break my if statement? Since, I will no longer be able to access list->next?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you want to modify a parameter's value (not the memory that it points to) you must pass a pointer to this parameter instead. You want to modify the parameter 'list' so it doesn't matter that list is already a pointer: you must pass a pointer to it.